# g++ doesn't call copy constructor if it is templated?

Tags: c++, templates

***tl;dr:*** copy constructor isn't called if it's preceded by `template<typename Something>`, and that `Something` is used in the constructor signature.

---

Proof-of-concept ([ideone](https://ideone.com/12e1Dr)):

```
#include <cstdio>

template<typename T>
class Test {
private:
    T value_;

public:
    mutable bool has_copies;

    Test(const T& value) : value_(value), has_copies(false) {}

    template<typename Related> // remove template here to fix behavior
    Test(const Test<Related>& t) {
        printf("In copy constructor\n");
        value_ = t.value_;
        has_copies = true;
        t.has_copies = true;
    }
};

int main() {
    Test<int> t1(42);
    printf("Before constructor\n");
    Test<int> t2(t1);
    printf("After constructor:\n");
    printf("    t1 thinks it %s copies\n", t1.has_copies ? "has" : "doesn't have");
    printf("    t2 thinks it %s copies\n", t2.has_copies ? "has" : "doesn't have");
}
```

Output:

```
Before constructor
After constructor:
    t1 thinks it doesn't have copies
    t2 thinks it doesn't have copies
```

Notice how `In copy constructor` isn't printed.

Making the copy constructor non-templated (i.e., removing `template<typename Related>` and changing `Related` to `T` in the signature) fixes the problem for me.

```
$ g++ --version
g++ (GCC) 6.2.1 20160830
```

Compilation & execution command:

```
g++ -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c++11 -O2 -Wshadow -Wformat=2 -Wfloat-equal -Wconversion -Wlogical-op -Wcast-qual -Wcast-align -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG -D_GLIBCXX_DEBUG_PEDANTIC -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -fno-sanitize-recover -fstack-protector "test.cpp" -o "test" && "test"
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A function template can never be a copy-constructor, even if instantiated with a type that would apparently make it match the expected signature for a copy-constructor. See [class.copy/2]:

> A non-template constructor for class X is a copy constructor if its first parameter is of type X&, const X&, volatile X& or const volatile X&, and either there are no other parameters or else all other parameters have default arguments.

All classes have an implicitly generated copy-constructor, if there is not a user-declared one (sometimes this may be defined as deleted), with signature:

```
Test(Test const &) = default;
```

When you write `Test<int> t2(t1);`, overload resolution selects the copy constructor instead of your template function because a non-template is preferred to a template, all other things being equal.

Note that if you changed your template function to `Test(Test<Related>& t)` then it would now be selected over the copy-constructor: "all other things" are no longer equal, and instantiating the template to exactly match `Test<int>` is preferred to the conversion adding `const` to match the copy constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)

> A copy constructor of class T is a non-template constructor whose first parameter is `T&`, `const T&`, `volatile T&`, or `const volatile T&`, and either there are no other parameters, or the rest of the parameters all have default values.

So, your constructor fails both on being a template, and not having the correct parameter type.